# Add 1 Histogram to side of Clustermap

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, heatmap, seaborn

Given this [`clustermap`](https://python-graph-gallery.com/405-dendrogram-with-heatmap-and-coloured-leaves/), how would I go about adding a bar chart/histogram to the right vertical axis (instead of having the names listed)?

I want the histogram to display the orange, yellow and brown column data on the right side.

I considered trying to use `sns.jointplot()` with `marginal_kws` from [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/82-marginal-plot-with-seaborn/), but that is for 2 histograms...so I tried adding just a histogram to the right, but I can't seem to get that to work properly.

```
# Libraries
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data set
url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df = df.set_index('model')
df

# Prepare a vector of color mapped to the 'cyl' column
my_palette = dict(zip(df.cyl.unique(), ["orange","yellow","brown"]))
row_colors = df.cyl.map(my_palette)

# plot
sns.clustermap(df, metric="correlation", method="single", cmap="Blues", standard_scale=1, row_colors=row_colors)
```

[image]

Attempt:

```
# Libraries
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data set
url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df = df.set_index('model')
df


# Prepare a vector of color mapped to the 'cyl' column
my_palette = dict(zip(df.cyl.unique(), ["orange","yellow","brown"]))
row_colors = df.cyl.map(my_palette)

# plot
cluster = sns.clustermap(df, metric="correlation", method="single", cmap="Blues", standard_scale=1, row_colors=row_colors)
sns.jointplot(cluster, cluster,  kind='clustermap')
```

[image: ATTEMPT]

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.barh(df['model'], df['cyl'])
```

[image]

Comment: The code is not runnable and you haven't even tried to put some histogram anywhere (that'll be the [reason it doesn't work](http://www.bestonlinecasino.com/images/stories/jokes/praying-for-the-lottery.jpg)).

Comment: It is runnable and breaks anytime I try to add a histogram. If you'd like me to add every failed picture of my attempts, I'd be glad to.

Comment: Ok, so this is admittedly not easy, but at the moment I don't even know what histogram you want to show. What you call `cluster` is a seaborn grid; of course you cannot draw a histogram of some seaborn class. Instead a histogram is created from *data*, via `plt.hist(data)`.

Comment: The data I'd like the histogram to show is the cyl column (the red, orange and brown one)

Comment: Histogram or horizontal bar plot--either one would work

Comment: If you can produce a separate figure with the histogram you want to show, I can provide you with a way to show it next to the clustermap. But you cannot expect me (or anyone else I suppose) to dive into the data and understand what histogram that would be; it seems the data is categorical, yet histograms are usually numeric.

Comment: Adding it to the question now

Comment: Shoot...I just realized the order of the names don't match :\

Comment: Do you have matplotlib 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: matplotlib 2.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `clustermap` creates its own figure one needs to do a little surgery to be able to add another plot to it.

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# Data set
url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df = df.set_index('model')
# Prepare a vector of color mapped to the 'cyl' column
my_palette = dict(zip(df.cyl.unique(), ["orange","yellow","brown"]))
row_colors = df.cyl.map(my_palette)

# plot clustermap
cluster = sns.clustermap(df, metric="correlation", method="single",
                         cmap="Blues", standard_scale=1, row_colors=row_colors)

#enlarge figure
cluster.fig.set_size_inches(8,6)
# make some space to the right in the figure
cluster.gs.update(right=0.95)
# divide existing axes
divider = make_axes_locatable(cluster.ax_heatmap)
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(cluster.ax_col_dendrogram)
# create new axes for bar plot 
ax = divider.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=1.7)
# create empty space of same size as bar plot axes (don't use this space)
nax = divider2.new_horizontal(size="20%", pad=1.7)

# Sort the values for the bar plot to have the same order as clusters
target = [t.get_text() for t in np.array(cluster.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels())]
ind= np.array([list(df.index.values).index(t) for t in target])

# plot bar plot in ax
ax.barh(np.arange(len(target)), df['cyl'].values[ind])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

ax.set_ylim(-0.5,len(df.index)-.5)
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image]